# Combining Text messages and Video

Tags: text, colors

I am using Adobe Flash Media Server. I am trying to do one 2 one video chat with clients exchanging text messages back and forth. I want to alternate different text colors such as red and blue to stand out well. I tried using css but it changes all the text colors not just each message.
Can find any examples at all in ActionScript. Please can somebody point me in the right direction?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add some source code of stuff you've already tried.

In general though, any text formatting, including colours, can be done via TextField.setTextFormat();

Also look at the TextFormat class.